# Ajax error in ubercart checkout - please help!

Tags: ajax, ubercart

I'm getting a massive ajax error when I click **calculate shipping** in [ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart). I cannot find anyone else experiencing this so I'm submitting the issue here.

No other ajax issues on the site that I have found. But when checking out of site store, getting this massive ajax error. Please help.

I am completely at a loss...

Thank you

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
[{
   "command":"settings",
   "settings":{
      "basePath":"\/",
      "pathPrefix":"",
      "ajaxPageState":{
         "theme":"erwin_pawn",
         "theme_token":"b8Rc9hSBL-KSshc-0lE_MAguBM53zKnW0JMom58t3fk"
      },
      "lightbox2":{
         "rtl":"0",
         "file_path":"\/(\\w\\w\/)public:\/",
         "default_image":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/lightbox2\/images\/brokenimage.jpg",
         "border_size":10,
         "font_color":"000",
         "box_color":"fff",
         "top_position":"",
         "overlay_opacity":"0.8",
         "overlay_color":"000",
         "disable_close_click":true,
         "resize_sequence":0,
         "resize_speed":400,
         "fade_in_speed":400,
         "slide_down_speed":600,
         "use_alt_layout":false,
         "disable_resize":false,
         "disable_zoom":false,
         "force_show_nav":false,
         "show_caption":true,
         "loop_items":false,
         "node_link_text":"View Image Details",
         "node_link_target":false,
         "image_count":"Image !current of !total",
         "video_count":"Video !current of !total",
         "page_count":"Page !current of !total",
         "lite_press_x_close":"press \u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 onclick=\u0022hideLightbox(); return FALSE;\u0022\u003E\u003Ckbd\u003Ex\u003C\/kbd\u003E\u003C\/a\u003E to close",
         "download_link_text":"Download Original",
         "enable_login":false,
         "enable_contact":false,
         "keys_close":"c x 27",
         "keys_previous":"p 37",
         "keys_next":"n 39",
         "keys_zoom":"z",
         "keys_play_pause":"32",
         "display_image_size":"",
         "image_node_sizes":"()",
         "trigger_lightbox_classes":"",
         "trigger_lightbox_group_classes":"",
         "trigger_slideshow_classes":"",
         "trigger_lightframe_classes":"",
         "trigger_lightframe_group_classes":"",
         "custom_class_handler":0,
         "custom_trigger_classes":"",
         "disable_for_gallery_lists":true,
         "disable_for_acidfree_gallery_lists":true,
         "enable_acidfree_videos":true,
         "slideshow_interval":5000,
         "slideshow_automatic_start":true,
         "slideshow_automatic_exit":true,
         "show_play_pause":true,
         "pause_on_next_click":false,
         "pause_on_previous_click":true,
         "loop_slides":false,
         "iframe_width":600,
         "iframe_height":400,
         "iframe_border":1,
         "enable_video":false
      },
      "popup":{
         "effects":{
            "show":{
               "default":"this.body.show();",
               "fade":"\n        if (this.opacity){\n          this.body.fadeTo(\u0027medium\u0027,this.opacity);\n        }else{\n          this.body.fadeIn(\u0027medium\u0027);\n        }",
               "slide-down":"this.body.slideDown(\u0027medium\u0027)",
               "slide-down-fade":"\n        this.body.animate(\n          {\n            height:\u0027show\u0027,\n            opacity:(this.opacity ? this.opacity : \u0027show\u0027)\n          }, \u0027medium\u0027\n        );"
            },
            "hide":{
               "default":"this.body.hide();",
               "fade":"this.body.fadeOut(\u0027medium\u0027);",
               "slide-down":"this.body.slideUp(\u0027medium\u0027);",
               "slide-down-fade":"\n        this.body.animate(\n          {\n            height:\u0027hide\u0027,\n            opacity:\u0027hide\u0027\n          }, \u0027medium\u0027\n        );"
            }
         },
         "linger":"250",
         "delay":"0"
      },
      "custom_search":{
         "form_target":"_self",
         "solr":0
      },
      "ajax":{
         "edit-panes-quotes-quote-button--2":{
            "effect":"slide",
            "progress":{
               "type":"bar",
               "message":"Receiving quotes..."
            },
            "callback":"uc_ajax_multiplex",
            "list":{
               "payment-pane":"uc_ajax_replace_checkout_pane",
               "quotes-pane":"uc_ajax_replace_checkout_pane"
            },
            "event":"mousedown",
            "keypress":true,
            "prevent":"click",
            "url":"\/system\/ajax",
            "submit":{
               "_triggering_element_name":"op",
               "_triggering_element_value":"Click to calculate shipping"
            }
         },
         "edit-panes-payment-payment-method-credit--2":{
            "callback":"uc_payment_checkout_payment_details",
            "wrapper":"payment-details",
            "progress":{
               "type":"throbber"
            },
            "event":"change",
            "url":"\/system\/ajax",
            "submit":{
               "_triggering_element_name":"panes[payment][payment_method]"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "merge":true
},
{
   "command":"insert",
   "method":"replaceWith",
   "selector":"#quotes-pane",
       "data":"
<fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="quotes-pane">
   <legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Calculate shipping cost</span></legend>
   <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
      <div class="fieldset-description">Shipping quotes are generated automatically when you enter your address and may be updated manually with the button below.</div>
      <input type="hidden" name="panes[quotes][uid]" value="1" />
      <input type="submit" id="edit-panes-quotes-quote-button--2" name="op" value="Click to calculate shipping" class="form-submit" />
      <div id="quote"></div>
   </div>
</fieldset>",
   "settings":null
},
{
   "command":"insert",
   "method":"prepend",
   "selector":"#quotes-pane",
   "data":"",
   "settings":null
},
{"command":"insert","method":"replaceWith","selector":"#payment-pane","data":"\u003Cfieldset class=\u0022form-wrapper\u0022 id=\u0022payment-pane\u0022\u003E\u003Clegend\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022fieldset-legend\u0022\u003EPayment method\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/legend\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022fieldset-wrapper\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\u0022line-items-div\u0022\u003E\u003Ctable id=\u0022uc-order-total-preview\u0022\u003E\u003Ctr class=\u0022line-item-subtotal\u0022\u003E\u003Ctd class=\u0022title\u0022\u003ESubtotal:\u003C\/td\u003E\u003Ctd class=\u0022price\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022uc-price\u0022\u003E$1,550.00\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/td\u003E\u003C\/tr\u003E\u003Ctr class=\u0022line-item-total\u0022\u003E\u003Ctd class=\u0022title\u0022\u003EOrder total:\u003C\/td\u003E\u003Ctd class=\u0022price\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022uc-price\u0022\u003E$1,550.00\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/td\u003E\u003C\/tr\u003E\u003C\/table\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-radios form-item-panes-payment-payment-method form-disabled\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Clabel class=\u0022element-invisible\u0022 for=\u0022edit-panes-payment-payment-method--2\u0022\u003EPayment method \u003Cspan class=\u0022form-required\u0022 title=\u0022This field is required.\u0022\u003E*\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/label\u003E\n \u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-panes-payment-payment-method--2\u0022 class=\u0022form-radios\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-radio form-item-panes-payment-payment-method form-disabled\u0022\u003E\n \u003Cinput disabled=\u0022disabled\u0022 type=\u0022radio\u0022 id=\u0022edit-panes-payment-payment-method-credit--2\u0022 name=\u0022panes[payment][payment_method]\u0022 value=\u0022credit\u0022 checked=\u0022checked\u0022 class=\u0022form-radio\u0022 \/\u003E  \u003Clabel class=\u0022option\u0022 for=\u0022edit-panes-payment-payment-method-credit--2\u0022\u003ECredit card: \u003Cimg class=\u0022uc-credit-cctype uc-credit-cctype-visa\u0022 typeof=\u0022Image\u0022 src=\u0022https:\/\/erwinpawninc.com\/sites\/all\/modules\/ubercart\/payment\/uc_credit\/images\/visa.gif\u0022 alt=\u0022Visa\u0022 \/\u003E \u003Cimg class=\u0022uc-credit-cctype uc-credit-cctype-mastercard\u0022 typeof=\u0022Image\u0022 src=\u0022https:\/\/erwinpawninc.com\/sites\/all\/modules\/ubercart\/payment\/uc_credit\/images\/mastercard.gif\u0022 alt=\u0022MasterCard\u0022 \/\u003E \u003Cimg class=\u0022uc-credit-cctype uc-credit-cctype-discover\u0022 typeof=\u0022Image\u0022 src=\u0022https:\/\/erwinpawninc.com\/sites\/all\/modules\/ubercart\/payment\/uc_credit\/images\/discover.gif\u0022 alt=\u0022Discover\u0022 \/\u003E \u003Cimg class=\u0022uc-credit-cctype uc-credit-cctype-amex\u0022 typeof=\u0022Image\u0022 src=\u0022https:\/\/erwinpawninc.com\/sites\/all\/modules\/ubercart\/payment\/uc_credit\/images\/amex.gif\u0022 alt=\u0022American Express\u0022 \/\u003E \u003C\/label\u003E\n\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv id=\u0022payment-details\u0022 class=\u0022clearfix payment-details-credit\u0022\u003E\u003Cp\u003EYour billing information must match the billing address for the credit card entered below or we will be unable to process your payment.\u003C\/p\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-textfield form-item-panes-payment-details-cc-number\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-panes-payment-details-cc-number--2\u0022\u003ECard number \u003C\/label\u003E\n \u003Cinput autocomplete=\u0022off\u0022 type=\u0022text\u0022 id=\u0022edit-panes-payment-details-cc-number--2\u0022 name=\u0022panes[payment][details][cc_number]\u0022 value=\u0022\u0022 size=\u002220\u0022 maxlength=\u002219\u0022 class=\u0022form-text\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-select form-item-panes-payment-details-cc-exp-month\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-panes-payment-details-cc-exp-month--2\u0022\u003EExpiration date \u003C\/label\u003E\n \u003Cselect id=\u0022edit-panes-payment-details-cc-exp-month--2\u0022 name=\u0022panes[payment][details][cc_exp_month]\u0022 class=\u0022form-select\u0022\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00221\u0022 selected=\u0022selected\u0022\u003E01 - January\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222\u0022\u003E02 - February\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00223\u0022\u003E03 - March\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00224\u0022\u003E04 - April\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00225\u0022\u003E05 - May\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00226\u0022\u003E06 - June\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00227\u0022\u003E07 - July\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00228\u0022\u003E08 - August\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00229\u0022\u003E09 - September\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002210\u0022\u003E10 - October\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002211\u0022\u003E11 - November\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002212\u0022\u003E12 - December\u003C\/option\u003E\u003C\/select\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-select form-item-panes-payment-details-cc-exp-year\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-panes-payment-details-cc-exp-year--2\u0022\u003EExpiration year \u003C\/label\u003E\n \u003Cselect id=\u0022edit-panes-payment-details-cc-exp-year--2\u0022 name=\u0022panes[payment][details][cc_exp_year]\
```

Comment: Is tax rate applying?

Comment: Could you get the full json request and pretty it up by using a tool like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. Also process the stuff in the "data" section of the json with this tool http://www.rapidmonkey.com/unicodeconverter/reverse.jsp

Comment: And then if that is HTML you can format it with this tool http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the links you provided Mike. I added the tax rate in and it continues to throw ajax error. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to help clarify what happened. I had installed Spider Facebook and it threw in some strange Facebook script that was causing this. Once that was removed, issue was solved. Thanks for everyone's help